# Find a selector and update

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a three different radio buttons and based on the selection of the radio button I would like to capture which radio button the user clicked and store that in a hidden input textbox for later use.

Here is the code I have tried, which doesn't seem to be working:

//clicked on first radioButton:

```
     $('#Employee').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) { 
            $('#multi').show();
            $('#Type').attr("EmployeeSelected"); 
         }
    });
```

//clicked on second radioButton:

```
    $('#Employer').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) { 
            $('#multi').show();
            $('#Type').attr("EmployerSelected"); 
         }
    });
```

My page looks like this:

```
<fieldset id="multi" class="fieldset-auto-width">
 <legend>
        Selected Form
 </legend>

<form action="/PostToDb" method="post">        
   <input type="text" name="Type" value="xx" />

  <div>
    ......................
  </div>
</form>
```

How do I update the textbox to whichever radio button is selected?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sn1hy78d/2/ check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input:radio[name=emp]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val()==0) {
        $("input:text").val('first radio');
    }else if ($(this).val()==1) {
        $("input:text").val('second radio');
    }else if ($(this).val()==2) {
        $("input:text").val('third radio');
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sn1hy78d/2/)

`$('#Employer')`--> when using `#` you will be selecting `id` as for `.` it is for class and so on.
`$('#Type').attr("EmployerSelected");` to assign a text to input use val() as `$('#Type').val("EmployerSelected");` meaning the element with `id` `Type` will have the value `EmployerSelected`

Comment: Added a few explaination. For further information.In my example only 1 so it wont hurt. @Max

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing .attr() with .val() and use the correct selector as follows:

```
$('[name="Type"]').val("EmployerSelected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add id attribute to the input box,as

```
 <input id="Type" type="text" name="Type" value="xx" />
```

hope helpful.